# Regex pattern for at least 1 char

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to setting a regex pattern that checks if a text has at least 1 character could be upper case or lower it won't matter

Text exemple : Hello world <---good pattern

I tried both of these and it always return false

```
 boolean b = Pattern.matches("/[A-Za-z]", title);  //it return false :( why?
```

I also tried

```
boolean b = Pattern.matches("/^[A-Za-z]+$/", title ); //it return false :( why?
```

I need some help understanding what I'm doing wrong

Much appreciation

Bass

Comment: What do you think the `/` do? Why do you think so? What does `matches` do? Does your character class account for spaces?

Comment: I did also tried boolean b = Pattern.matches("[A-Za-z]", title);  ...still returned false

Comment: What does `matches` do? Does it look for occurrences or tries to match the entire input?

Comment: Well , it has to match the entire input , the whole String

Comment: Does `[A-Za-z]` match the entirety of `"hello world"`? In other words, is `"hello world"` made up of a single character between A-Z or a-z?

Comment: Try using a pattern testing website to help debug input patterns. One example is [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html). Use multiple test examples, such as "A", "Ab", and "Hello World".

Comment: @KevinO wow! this will help me a lot thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "good" `String` also includes white space (and your regular expression shouldn't include `/`s). Something like,

```
String title = "Hello world";
boolean b = Pattern.matches("^[A-Za-z\\s]+$", title);
```

Will set `b` to `true`.

Comment: Ohhh , this actually true , if you don't mind  it ok to help me understand how to include characters like  "é" exemple : héllo world (should also return true) Or I should open another question? Thanks again for help , best regards

Comment: Aren't the start/end anchors implicit when calling `matches()`?